# EclipseLink: don't fetch some fields by default

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Let's say we have an entity

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id int id;
    @Basic String name;
    @Basic String remark;
}
```

Let's say "remark" field is filled with big texts, but rarely used. So it would be good if when you run jpql: `SELECT p FROM Person p`, EclipseLink just executes sql `select id, name from person`

And than when you call `person.getRemark()`, it will get fetched with `select remark from person where id = ?`.

Is it possible with EclipseLink 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add annotation `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id int id;
    @Basic String name;
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) String remark;
}
```

Comment: Won't that still fetch `remark` every time a Person is fetched?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but according to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_JPA_(ELUG)#.40Lob , EclipseLink should support lazy lob

Comment: @nanda Doesn't the documentation there conflict with http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Lazy_Basics that defines BASIC as EGAR

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed define a `fetch` attribute in a `Basic` annotation and set it to `LAZY`. But let me quote what the specification says about it:

> #### 11.1.6 Basic Annotation
>
> (...)
>
> The `EAGER` strategy is a requirement
>   on the persistence provider runtime
>   that data must be eagerly fetched.
>   **The `LAZY` strategy is *a hint* to the persistence provider runtime that
>   data should be fetched lazily when it
>   is first accessed. The implementation
>   is permitted to eagerly fetch data for
>   which the `LAZY` strategy hint has
>   been specified.** In particular, lazy
>   fetching might only be available for
>   `Basic` mappings for which
>   property-based access is used.

In the particular case of EclipseLink, the behavior will depend on the context (Java EE vs Java SE) as explained in [What You May Need to Know About EclipseLink JPA Lazy Loading](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#What_You_May_Need_to_Know_About_EclipseLink_JPA_Lazy_Loading).

In a Java EE environment (assuming the container *implements the appropriate container contracts of the EJB 3.0 specification*):

> EclipseLink JPA performs lazy loading when the fetch attribute is set to javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY.

In a Java SE environment:

> By default, EclipseLink JPA ignores the
>   fetch attribute and default javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER applies.
>
> To configure EclipseLink JPA to perform lazy loading when the fetch attribute set to FetchType.LAZY, consider one of the following:
>
> - [How to Configure Dynamic Weaving for JPA Entities Using the EclipseLink Agent](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Configure_Dynamic_Weaving_for_JPA_Entities_Using_the_EclipseLink_Agent)
> - [How to Configure Static Weaving for JPA Entities](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Configure_Static_Weaving_for_JPA_Entities)

Comment: Your links are dead... (;_;)

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem (when using ActiveRecord and Hibernate) by putting the large string (usually a CLOB or BLOB) into it's own table with a FK to the main table (Person in this case.)  Then it works like you want.